# Python Selenium won't select all image tags

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to crawl Product Hunt using Selenium

More specifically I am trying to get the source link for all the icons of the products.

HTML:

[image: here is the html code]

My code for crawling is the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("<Your driver's path>")
driver.get("https://www.producthunt.com/topics/seo-tools?order=most-upvoted")
time.sleep(4)
icons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.styles_thumbnail__d2DAK.styles_thumbnail__XBHZ_ img")
print(len(icons))
print(icons)
driver.close()
```

The problem is that selenium only gets the 3 first pictures and not all the products available.

I have tried increasing the sleep time as well as implemented the driver.wait way along with `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` to be sure that all icons are loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other icons show when you scroll at the bottom of the page, you can do like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.producthunt.com/topics/seo-tools?order=most-upvoted")

expected_number_of_icons = 20

icons = []
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    icons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@data-test, 'post-item')]//div[@class='styles_thumbnail__d2DAK styles_thumbnail__XBHZ_']//img | //div[contains(@class, 'styles_link')]//span[@class='lazyload-wrapper']/img")))
    icons = list(set(icons))
    if len(icons) > expected_number_of_icons:
        break

icons = icons[:expected_number_of_icons]
driver.close()
```

where you choose to stop when you reach the number of icons that you want. Obviously, for example if you reach 210 icons and you want only 200 icons you can discard the last 10 elements of the list

Comment: It seem to be getting more icons but it skips some and I want to crawl the first 20 lets say.

Comment: Yes because It will find duplicates. I edited the answer in order to remove duplicates. Try with this and if It skips some check if they have a differenti path and add the other paths to the original one with an or condition

Comment: Hmm still it gets random images. It is quite weird to me that this happens only for images

Comment: What do you mean with random images? Doesn't it return only icons? Does it return other images in the page?

Comment: No I mean it skips some images. I want the first 20

Comment: Inspect the page and with Control + F or Command + F put the xpath in the search bar and check if the path finds all the first 20 elements. If It skips some icon add the path of the skipped icons to my xpath or try to find an univoque xpath for all the icons

Comment: try with `visibility_of_all_elements_located` instead of `presence_of_all_elements_located`and tell me if it works

Comment: Nope man still it return random images. The weird thing is that I can crawl the divs that contain the images but not the images themselves.

Comment: Mh yes I tried again and it skips some image. It is really weird since the xpath scans the icons well. I tried also to scroll first and then get the images bit without results :/

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the *src* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.lazyload-wrapper > img")])
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='lazyload-wrapper']/img")])
  ```

---

Ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.producthunt.com/topics/seo-tools?order=most-upvoted')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.lazyload-wrapper > img")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` in a single line:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.producthunt.com/topics/seo-tools?order=most-upvoted')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='lazyload-wrapper']/img")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Still it only returns only the first four icons and I want to get all the first bunch of icons. If I crawl the divs I get all 20 but not the case with icons

Comment: @z3y50n Never mind :) Seems you got an accepted answer